# Get "DNA" of one parent based on its children

Tags: genetics, dna, bioinformatics, homework, allele

I'm no biology expert so bear with me, but I've been given a task to estimate alleles of an animal based on the animal's children and the children's other parents.

I've looked up Mendel's laws but I'm not sure I can possibly determine the correct result - better show an example:

Let us say that we want to get alleles of a mother. We know the following:

Child 1 has alleles: **AG**, the father of the child has alleles: **AG**
Child 2 has alleles: **GG**, the father of the child has alleles: **GG**
Child 3 has alleles: **GG**, the father of the child has alleles: **GG**

According to Mendel's laws and the example above it would seem that
For the first child x father pair - the mother would have alleles **AG**
For the second and third child x father pair - the mother would have alleles either **GG** or it could have **AG**, **CG** or **TG**.

How can I determine which anwser is correct?

If needed I can provide more examples.

---

EDIT: More examples / clarification

I have a database of animals (cows/bulls). Each animal has ~50 000 SNPs, each SNP has 2 alleles.

However, some of the animals data are missing, for instance I do not have SNPs for a certain bull, but I do have SNPs of the bull's children and their mothers.

Now I need to figure out an algorithm that based on the SNPs of said children and the SNPs of their mothers tries to compute the SNPs of the bull.

Additional example: (each row represents a child - mother pair)
SNP                                 | Child alleles | Mother alleles | Possible father alleles
ARS-BFGL-BAC-19454  | GG               | AG                   | AG, GG 
ARS-BFGL-BAC-19454  | AA                | AG                   | AG, AA

From the table above it is clear that the bull can only have AG.

However I do not know how to handle the following case:
SNP                                 | Child alleles | Mother alleles | Possible father alleles
ARS-BFGL-BAC-14220  | AG               | AG                   | AA, AG, GG 
ARS-BFGL-BAC-14220  | GG               | GG                   | GG, AG, CG, TG
From the table above it looks like the bull can have either AG or GG - how do I figure out whether the father's value is AG or GG?

Comment: It requires a bit of Bayesian statistics.

Comment: It would help to get the actual prompt or question that you are trying to answer. For example, do the alleles `{A, G}` cover the total set of alleles at this locus? In that case some genotypes could be ruled out. There are cases in which you _can_ infer parental genotypes, but some more information is required. Is this a homework question?

Comment: You can't be certain. Is this a real data set you are working on or something used in, say, a course?

Comment: @MaximilianPress I've tried to make it more clear in the original post. I do not know if the alleles cover the total set of alleles at this locus, frankly I do not even know what a locus is (as I said, I'm not a biologist).

Comment: @BryanKrause It is a real data set.

Comment: If you have real data you can't always find the answer definitively. Vadim gives good advice for getting the probabilities.

Comment: @BryanKrause I'm not sure how would I get the probability for the SNP ARS-BFGL-BAC-14220. Three of the children - mother pairs are AG - AG, while nine of them are GG - GG. Howver all twelve pairs can get me either a AG or GG combination. To me it seems like it is always 50:50 between AG and GG, am I missing something? 
(In this case the GG is the correct answer as I am testing the algorithm on data that I do have).

Comment: @toucheqt You aren't being very clear about the data you have, and I don't really want to go around and around trying to find out and solve your problem for you. I think you've got some information to run with - see where that gets you after you give it a couple days thought. You'll learn a lot more trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I think I can answer somewhat usefully with the update.

It's helpful in this case to think in terms of sampling alleles. It's true that the cases that you give are not 100% unambiguous, but it is not true that we can't give a somewhat confident estimate. We can still make a statistical prediction of the most probable genotype.

The first thing to note is that you are working with *pedigrees*. That is, you have parents and multiple children. Pedigrees are great because they allow you to pool information across individuals.

The next thing to note is that your alleles are almost certainly not of uniform frequency in the population. In other words, If I sample a random cow from the herd, the probability of allele $A$ at some arbitrary locus is almost certainly not the same as the probability of allele $G$. You can use that information in inferring the most likely allele. Moreover, you can put a precise number on the probability of any given allele.

The simplest method I can think of is to use [genotype likelihoods](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4613-0035-9_7), to account for pedigree information, and to incorporate the background allele frequency as a prior probability (h/t Vadim for the Bayesian approach).

A [likelihood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood_function) is the probability of some dataset given a specific hypothesis. In other words, your data is your offspring genotypes and your hypothesis would be the different offspring.

In your first example, we can logically rule out alleles other than $AG$. (That's actually not true; you should account for the possibility of genotyping error, but we'll ignore that for now.)

In your second example, we can't logically rule out all but one genotype. But we can say some things nonetheless:

- you have said that there are only 2 alleles per locus (i.e. $A$ and $G$ are the only possible alleles).
- $A$ and $G$ have distinct frequencies in the population.
- we now *at least one* paternal allele ($G$).

Let's take a simple case of the likelihood application, in which we say that frequency of $Pr(A) = 0.9$ and $Pr(G) = 0.1$ (I am making these numbers up). Now in the ambiguous case:

$$Pr(paternal=GG | offspring\_genotypes=GG,AG) = \\
Pr(offspring\_genotypes = GG,AG|paternal=GG) * Pr(paternal=GG) = \\
Pr(offspring=GG | paternal=GG, maternal=GG) \\
* Pr(offspring=AG | paternal=GG, maternal=AG) * Pr(paternal=GG)
$$

and

$$Pr(paternal=AG | offspring\_genotypes=GG,AG) = \\
Pr(offspring\_genotypes = GG,AG | paternal=AG) * Pr(paternal=AG) = \\
Pr(offspring=GG | paternal=AG, maternal=GG) \\
* Pr(offspring AG | paternal=AG, maternal=AG) * Pr(paternal=AG)
$$

Which evaluate to:

$Pr(paternal GG) = 1.0 * (0.5 * 0.5 + 0.5 * 0.5) * (0.1 * 0.1) = 0.005$

and

$Pr(paternal AG) = (1.0 * 0.5) * (0.5 * 0.5 + 0.5 * 0.5) * (0.5 * 0.1) = 0.0125$

You can see that there are multiple ways for the offspring to get genotypes in the paternal $AG$ case, which is what leads to the terms with addition. Note also that the $Pr(paternal genotype)$ at the end handles the genotype frequency, as all the other terms are conditioned on the parental genotypes.

So in this highly artificial example, we prefer genotype of $AG$ somewhat (note that these likelihoods do not sum to 1.0). But, if we were to alter the genotype frequencies to 50% frequency of each allele, we would get:

$Pr(paternal GG) = 1.0 * (0.5 * 0.5 + 0.5 * 0.5) * (0.5 * 0.5) = 0.125$

and

$Pr(paternal AG) = (1.0 * 0.5) * (0.5 * 0.5 + 0.5 * 0.5) * (0.5 * 0.5) = 0.0625$

and you would come to the opposite conclusion!

So it really matters what the background frequency is, if you choose to consider that term.

You could also think about genotyping error or whatever as part of these calculations.

**I am certain that there is a more sophisticated way to do this, that takes better advantage of available information, etc. Maybe I've even made a mistake in the computation- but this is an approach that you might use to infer paternal genotypes.**

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, it helped a lot.

Comment: Good! I should note that this is a Bayesian approach to compute a posterior probability, and therefore probably similar to what Vadim first suggested.

Comment: I think you deserve the full credit for working through the calculations.